# How to convert int array back to pandas timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am able to convert a numpy-array column of type `pandas timestamp` to an int array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [pd.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 5, 30, 1), pd.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 5, 30, 1), pd.datetime(2019, 1, 11, 5, 30, 1)], 'b': [np.nan, 5.1, 1.6]})

a = df.to_numpy()
a
# array([[Timestamp('2019-01-11 05:30:01'), nan],
#       [Timestamp('2019-01-11 05:30:01'), 5.1],
#       [Timestamp('2019-01-11 05:30:01'), 1.6]], dtype=object)
a[:,0] = a[:,0].astype('datetime64').astype(np.int64)
# array([[1547184601000000, nan],
#        [1547184601000000, 5.1],
#        [1547184601000000, 1.6]], dtype=object)
```

For this array a, I would like to convert the column 0 back to a pandas timestamp. As the array is quite big and my overall process quite time consuming, I would like to avoid the usage of python loops, applys, lambdas or similar things. Instead, I am looking for speed optimized native numpy based functions etc.

I tried already things like:

```
a[:,0].astype('datetime64')
```

(result: `ValueError: Converting an integer to a NumPy datetime requires a specified unit`)

and:

```
import calendar
calendar.timegm(a[:,0].utctimetuple())
```

(result: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'utctimetuple'`)

How can I convert my column `a[:,0]` back to

```
array([[Timestamp('2019-01-11 05:30:01'), nan],
      [Timestamp('2019-01-11 05:30:01'), 5.1],
      [Timestamp('2019-01-11 05:30:01'), 1.6]], dtype=object)
```

in a speed optimized way?

Comment: What do you mean "back to", I can't see the difference between your original data with the desired output?

Comment: I mean with 'back to' that I get from the column with `int`s ('1547184601000000' etc.) back to the Timestamps (`'2019-01-11 05:30:01'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

> Immutable ndarray of datetime64 data, represented internally as int64, and which can be boxed to Timestamp objects that are subclasses of datetime and carry metadata such as frequency information.

So, we can use `DatetimeIndex`. and then covert it by using `np.int64`.

```
In [18]: b = a[:,0]                                                             

In [19]: index = pd.DatetimeIndex(b)

In [21]: index.astype(np.int64)                                                 
Out[21]: Int64Index([1547184601000000000, 1547184601000000000, 1547184601000000000], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. You have to multipy by 1000 though, to get the right result: `pd.DatetimeIndex(a[:,0]*1e3)`

Comment: `can be boxed to` - what does that mean?

Comment: @wwii To explain your question, I think you should check the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html